# How to replace object data with that of another object of the same class in Java?

Tags: java

I have an object a1 in java of a class Afoo and an object a2 of the same class how to make a1 take the data from a2 ?

That's what I'm doing here with the replace method in the example below, but, is there an easier way than writing this method? because writing this method is tedious for large classes ...

```
class Afoo {
 public int m1;
 public String s1;
 public ArrayList<int> arr;

 public Afoo (int m1, String s1 , ArrayList<int> arr){
  this.m1 = m1;
  this.s1 = s1;
  this.arr = arr;
 }
 
 public void replace (Afoo a)
 {
   this.m1 = a.m1;
   this.s1 = a.s1;
   this.arr = a.arr;

 }
```

Comment: Would it make your life easier if you decided to use `a2` instead of repurposing `a1` with all the data from `a2`? Presumably there are reasons why you decided not to do this

Comment: That is strange.  Normally you would create a new Afoo from the calling context.  How many classes do you have?  You only have to code it once.  If you have a class with 100 elements in it, then that may be a design issue.

Comment: I just realized that it would be easier to use a2 indeed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no other ways to achive the required task. Or else you can [clone a required object](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clone-method-in-java-2/)  and assing it to the existing object. It depends on what you want to achive.